# udf to replace the datediff function value error

Tags: user-defined-functions, datediff

I am trying to make a udf to replace the datediff function.
reason: the udf will end up in my very (close to 8192 limit) long formula.
I use the "dutch" vba therefor datediff is "datumverschil" (a long word)
I want to replace it with "dv"
but so far my dv udf is not working, and I cannot guess where the error
could be... the error says "error in value"...

this is what I have now:

```
Public Function dv(eerste As Date, tweede As Date, str As String) As Variant

dv = DateDiff(str, eerste, tweede)

End Function
```

who sees the error :) ? have a great sunday and thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the language you are using, but normally each argument in a function has to go in order. Maybe this is your error?

In your code you have:

```
Public Function dv(eerste As Date, tweede As Date, str As String) As Variant
```

As you can probably see here, eerste goes first, tweede goes second, and str goes last.

So to pass the arguments through properly you would have to do:

`dv(eerste, tweede, str)`

Hope this solves your issue and have a nice day! :)

Edit:

I also noticed your function and your variable are named the same?
Again im not sure what language you are using, but it seems assigning `DateDiff` to the `dv` variable, you would be overwriting the function?

Perhaps you meant `DateDiff = dv(eerste, tweede, str)`